# Android: Is there any use case where internal file storage can cause an IOException?

Tags: android, storage, ioexception

If I [save or load data to or from the internal storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage), it could cause an IOException. But I have no clue when this should happen. The only use case could probably be when you run out of space, but is there anything else which could cause this Exception here? (For example some right management configuration on the user side).
And when can this Exception occur while read operation? I don't even know any use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

`The only use case could probably be when you run out of space.`

Other cases:

- The parent directory does not exist. For example, you're trying to access `/data/data/packagename/some_custom_dir_not_yet_created/my_file`. You'd need to first call `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()`.
- The file you're trying to read does not exist. `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`.
- You app is trying to read / write to another app's internal storage.